# div keeps overflowing no matter what (details inside)

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this page and click on the arrows to activate the carousel: http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/browse/divisions/i

As you can see, the `ul` overflows over the div with the black background, I need to fix this.

I've created a class called `.stop_overflowing_plz` and inside of that I've put a `ul` which is part of the carousel you see. The purpose of that new class is to stop the `ul` from overflowing all the way over the black div, but isn't working as intended.

Anyone know what I could do in order to keep the `ul` inside of `.stop_overflowing_plz` and stop it from overflowing like it currently is doing?

Comment: Please add some code.  The CSS for the class mentioned would be very helpful

Comment: Hello, can you extract the css and html you are refering to, help us help you :-)

Comment: the css can be viewed by just right clicking and pressing **n** in chrome, i'm sure firefox has something similar. Thanks for replying though, the problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have the following CSS applied to the `ul`:

```
.le_carousel .overview {
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
left: 0 top: 0;
}
```

You need to change `position` to `relative` otherwise it will always position itself relative to the page and not the surrounding div.

Comment: Or change it on the stop_overflowing_plz div

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: relative` to your `stop_overflowing_plz` `div`.

As you're setting `position: absolute` on your `ul`, you need to make your `div` the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block).